# Hibernate: Unable to access aggregate value in "group by" when used "NEW constructor" in query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a below requirement to find all the stores within a range from the current location.
    For that I am using the below query:

```
SELECT NEW com.slocamo.rest.entity.Store(s,(((acos(sin((:lat*pi()/180))*sin((location_latitude*pi()/180))+cos((:lat*pi()/180))*cos((location_latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((:lng - location_longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance) FROM Store s group by distance having distance < (:rangeInMeters * 0.00062137119) order by distance ASC

When I execute the query, it is throwing below error 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'distance' in 'group statement'

I have made the distance column as transient.
```

How to make "distance" visible or is there an alternative to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

```
Belw is my Store class.

package com.slocamo.rest.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "stores")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "searchStore", query = "SELECT distinct s FROM Store s where LOWER(store_title) "
                + "like LOWER(:searchString) OR LOWER(store_address) like LOWER(:searchString) OR LOWER(store_city) "
                + "like LOWER(:searchString) OR LOWER(store_state) like LOWER(:searchString) OR LOWER(store_country) "
                + "like LOWER(:searchString)"),

        @NamedQuery(name = "searchStoreCount", query = "SELECT count(*) FROM Store s where LOWER(store_title) "
                + "like LOWER(:searchString) OR LOWER(store_address) like LOWER(:searchString) OR LOWER(store_city) "
                + "like LOWER(:searchString) OR LOWER(store_state) like LOWER(:searchString) OR LOWER(store_country) "
                + "like LOWER(:searchString)"),

        @NamedQuery(name = "getStoresMapIfLocKnown", query = "SELECT NEW com.slocamo.rest.entity.Store(s,(((acos(sin((:lat*pi()/180))*sin((location_latitude*pi()/180))+cos((:lat*pi()/180))*cos((location_latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((:lng - location_longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515)) FROM Store s group by distance having distance < (:rangeInMeters * 0.00062137119) order by distance ASC") })
public class Store {
    public static final String SEARCH_STORE = "searchStore";
    public static final String SEARCH_STORE_COUNT = "searchStoreCount";
    public static final String GET_STORES_MAP_IF_LOC_KNOWN = "getStoresMapIfLocKnown";

    public Store() {

    }
    public Store(Store s, Double distance) {
        this.setDistance(distance);
        this.idstore = s.idstore;
        this.is_active = s.is_active;
        this.location_latitude=s.location_latitude;
        this.location_longitude = s.location_longitude;
        this.postal_code = s.postal_code;
        this.store_address= s.store_address;
        this.store_address2 = s.store_address2;
        this.store_city = s.store_city;
        this.store_contact = s.store_contact;
        this.store_country=s.store_country;
        this.store_county = s.store_county;
        this.store_state = s.store_state;
        this.store_title = s.store_title;
        this.uid = s.uid;
    }
    @Id
    private Long idstore;
    @Column
    private String store_title;
    @Column
    private String store_address;
    @Column
    private String store_address2;
    private String store_city;
    private String store_state;
    private String store_country;
    private Double location_latitude;
    private Double location_longitude;
    private Long uid;
    // As it is not required to be displayed
    // private Long idcredit_card;
    private String store_contact;
    private String postal_code;
    private String store_county;
    private Boolean is_active;

    @Transient
    private Double distance;
    /**
     * @return the idstore
     */
    public Long getIdstore() {
        return idstore;
    }

    /**
     * @param idstore
     *            the idstore to set
     */
    public void setIdstore(Long idstore) {
        this.idstore = idstore;
    }

    /**
     * @return the store_title
     */
    public String getStore_title() {
        return store_title;
    }

    /**
     * @param store_title
     *            the store_title to set
     */
    public void setStore_title(String store_title) {
        this.store_title = store_title;
    }

    /**
     * @return the store_address
     */
    public String getStore_address() {
        return store_address;
    }

    /**
     * @param store_address
     *            the store_address to set
     */
    public void setStore_address(String store_address) {
        this.store_address = store_address;
    }

    /**
     * @return the store_address2
     */
    public String getStore_address2() {
        return store_address2;
    }

    /**
     * @param store_address2
     *            the store_address2 to set
     */
    public void setStore_address2(String store_address2) {
        this.store_address2 = store_address2;
    }

    /**
     * @return the store_city
     */
    public String getStore_city() {
        return store_city;
    }

    /**
     * @param store_city
     *            the store_city to set
     */
    public void setStore_city(String store_city) {
        this.store_city = store_city;
    }

    /**
     * @return the store_state
     */
    public String getStore_state() {
        return store_state;
    }

    /**
     * @param store_state
     *            the store_state to set
     */
    public void setStore_state(String store_state) {
        this.store_state = store_state;
    }

    /**
     * @return the store_country
     */
    public String getStore_country() {
        return store_country;
    }

    /**
     * @param store_country
     *            the store_country to set
     */
    public void setStore_country(String store_country) {
        this.store_country = store_country;
    }

    /**
     * @return the location_latitude
     */
    public Double getLocation_latitude() {
        return location_latitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param location_latitude
     *            the location_latitude to set
     */
    public void setLocation_latitude(Double location_latitude) {
        this.location_latitude = location_latitude;
    }

    /**
     * @return the location_longitude
     */
    public Double getLocation_longitude() {
        return location_longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param location_longitude
     *            the location_longitude to set
     */
    public void setLocation_longitude(Double location_longitude) {
        this.location_longitude = location_longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @return the uid
     */
    public Long getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    /**
     * @param uid
     *            the uid to set
     */
    public void setUid(Long uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    /**
     * @return the store_contact
     */
    public String getStore_contact() {
        return store_contact;
    }

    /**
     * @param store_contact
     *            the store_contact to set
     */
    public void setStore_contact(String store_contact) {
        this.store_contact = store_contact;
    }

    /**
     * @return the postal_code
     */
    public String getPostal_code() {
        return postal_code;
    }

    /**
     * @param postal_code
     *            the postal_code to set
     */
    public void setPostal_code(String postal_code) {
        this.postal_code = postal_code;
    }

    /**
     * @return the store_county
     */
    public String getStore_county() {
        return store_county;
    }

    /**
     * @param store_county
     *            the store_county to set
     */
    public void setStore_county(String store_county) {
        this.store_county = store_county;
    }

    /**
     * @return the is_active
     */
    public Boolean getIs_active() {
        return is_active;
    }

    /**
     * @param is_active
     *            the is_active to set
     */
    public void setIs_active(Boolean is_active) {
        this.is_active = is_active;
    }
    /**
     * @return the distance
     */
    public Double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }
    /**
     * @param distance the distance to set
     */
    public void setDistance(Double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your named queries as NamedNativeQuery instead NamedQuery because of your query type.

I think your queries are SQL. **count(*)** is a SQL statement.

--->NamedQuery for JPQL

--->NamedNativeQuery for SQL

Notice that your query must follow each language syntax. Both SQL and JPQL syntax are different partly.